# Arraylist is showing only 1 value in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview in which i am getting data set and saving value from data set into another arraylist and save them in shared preference and getting same arraylist in another activity . But problem is that Arraylist is always showing only 1 value. Pls help me out to resolve.

code:-

```
 //here i am adding items to another arraylist
                        ArrayList<WhiteListModel> res = new ArrayList<WhiteListModel>();
                        WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
                        whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(position).getName());
                        whiteListModel.setPackName(listStorage.get(position).getPackName());
                        res.add(whiteListModel);
                        saveScoreListToSharedpreference(res);

/**
 * Save list of scores to own sharedpref
 *
 * @param scoresList
 */
private void saveScoreListToSharedpreference(ArrayList<WhiteListModel> scoresList) {
    sharedPreference = new MySharedPreference(mContext);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //convert ArrayList object to String by Gson
    String jsonScore = gson.toJson(scoresList);
    Log.e(TAG, "LIST::" + jsonScore);

    //save to shared preference
    sharedPreference.saveHighScoreList(jsonScore);
}
```

code for MySharedPreference

```
 private SharedPreferences pref;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
// Context
private Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "pref";
private static final String SCORES = "scores";

public MySharedPreference(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void saveHighScoreList(String scoreString) {
    editor.putString(SCORES, scoreString);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getHighScoreList() {
    return pref.getString(SCORES, "");
}
```

}

code of SwitchCompatButton

```
listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        ArrayList<WhiteListModel> res = null;
                        for (int position = 0; position < listStorage.size(); position++) {
                            //here i am adding items to another arraylist
                            res = new ArrayList<WhiteListModel>();
                            WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
                            whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(position).getName());
                            whiteListModel.setPackName(listStorage.get(position).getPackName());
                            res.add(whiteListModel);

                        }
                        saveScoreListToSharedpreference(res);


                        listStorage.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: add your MySharedPreference class

Comment: see i have edited that one

Comment: You have added only one item to arraylist.

Comment: You are adding only 1 item so how are you expecting more in list?

Comment: how if i add multiple

Comment: use addall method

Comment: showing error in res.addAll(whiteListModel); arraylist cannot be applied

Comment: you have tried to add a class to arraylist,addall method use to add a arraylist to another arraylist

Comment: res .addAll(listStorage);

Answer (score 0):

When you add multiple elements to the array list using a loop please remember to instantiate the object again.

```
for(int position=0;position<10;position++){
WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel(); //has to be done repeatedly

 whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(position).getName());

whiteListModel.setPackName(listStorage.get(position).getPackName());
                    res.add(whiteListModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding only one item to array list so you retrieve only one item. You should add more items to it. You can do it in following way.

```
ArrayList<WhiteListModel> res = new ArrayList<WhiteListModel>();
for(int i = 0; i < listStorage.size(); i++){

                    WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
                    whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(i).getName());
                    whiteListModel.setPackName(listStorage.get(i).getPackName());
                    res.add(whiteListModel);
                    saveScoreListToSharedpreference(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting only one value, you are not using loop to insert value. you have to change code like this.

```
 for(int position=o;position<listStorage.size;position++)

{
    ArrayList<WhiteListModel> res = new ArrayList<WhiteListModel>();
    WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
    whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    whiteListModel.setPackName(listStorage.get(position).getPackName());
    res.add(whiteListModel);
}

  itemtext.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                if (isChecked) {

                    menuEnquiryCartBean = new MenuEnquiryCartBean();

                    itemList.add(menuEnquirycartBean.getName());
                   // itemList.add(mainList.get(i).getName());
                    buttonView.setChecked(true);

                    Toast.makeText(context, buttonView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else {
                    itemList.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());
                    buttonView.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(context, buttonView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: see scenarioe is that i have a dataset called liststorage from which i have to add selected items into another arraylist which i am doing......not whole liststorage

Comment: tell me about on what basis you are adding in other list.

Comment: WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
                                whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(position).getName());
                                whiteListModel.setPackName(listStorage.get(position).getPackName());

Comment: you misunderstood my point, i'm saying how you are doing  by forget data.

Comment: but you are not defining what do you want to insert ,if you used loop than whole data will be inserted not your choice.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to te;;

Comment: simply tell me , on what basis you are differentiating data to be inserted.

Comment: I have listview from which i select two index let suppose item 1 and item 2 and want to add the same into another Arraylist......listStorage is parent data set from which i want to add 2 selected items into another data set called ArrayList<WhiteListModel>

Comment: okay your are using check box or something else to select data.

Comment: you don't need to add loop inside onCheckedChanged because it gives you particular position data and you just need to add directly because you are doing this code in adapter class. just you need to satisfy condition that the switch button is open or not .

Comment: but if i select two items then in second listview only 1 item is visisble

Comment: have a look on my code , I'm also doing this but i'm using check box.

Comment: it is perfectly working for me, and specially you don't need to define bean class for it, it gives you bean data when select anything.

Comment: I am confused after saw your code ...not understand what to add or what to not

Comment: if you are doing all this thing in adapter class than don't need to specify what data you want to insert, when you click particular switch than it would be automatically store because it is associated with every single item of list.

Comment: what is itemList

Comment: itemlist is your new item list.

Comment: simply you can write like this if you are using bean data calss.  itemList.add(bean.getName());

Comment: and don't want to use bean than you can directly get data from you adapter main list like itemList.add(mainList.get(i).getName()); and you have to make i as final variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148783/discussion-between-farhana-and-niraj).